# Multiple categories filtering with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm completely new to databases, but at the time I'm trying to implement a filter with multiple categories using checkboxes. Let's say I have some database with 3 tables: games, attributes and values. Here I'm trying to implement some EAV db model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `game_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `games` (`id`, `game_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Grand Theft Auto Vice City'),
(2, 'Counter Strike 1.6'),
(3, 'Fallout 2'),
(4, 'Minecraft');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attributes` (
  `attr_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY (`attr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `attributes` (`attr_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES
(1, 'release'),
(2, 'developer'),
(3, 'country');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `values` (
  `entity_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `values` (`entity_id`, `attribute_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2002'),
(1, 2, 'Rockstar'),
(1, 3, 'USA'),
(2, 1, '2000'),
(2, 2, 'Valve'),
(2, 3, 'USA'),
(3, 1, '1998'),
(3, 2, 'Black Isle Studios'),
(3, 3, 'USA'),
(4, 1, '2011'),
(4, 2, 'Mojang'),
(4, 3, 'Sweden');

ALTER TABLE `values`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `values_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`attr_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `values_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`id`);
```

My index.html has some filter with checkboxes and three categories of filtering: release date, developer and country of developing:

```
<form id="filter">
 <h2>Date of release:</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1998" name="1988"><label for="1988">1988</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2000" name="2000"><label for="2000">2000</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2002" name="2002"><label for="2002">2002</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2011" name="2011"><label for="2011">2011</label>

<h2>Developer:</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="rockstar" name="Rockstar"><label for="rockstar">Rockstar</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="valve" name="Valve"><label for="valve">Valve</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="black-isle-studios" name="Black Isle Studios"><label for="black-isle-studios">Black Isle Studios</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="mojang" name="Mojang"><label for="mojang">Mojang</label>

<h2>Country:</h2>
  <input type="checkbox" id="usa" name="USA"><label for="usa">USA</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="sweden" name="Sweden"><label for="sweden">Sweden</label><br>
</form>
```

Here is some JS I use to compile data from client side and send it with ajax query:

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  var opts = getGamesFilterOptions();
  updateGames(opts);
});

function getGamesFilterOptions(){
  var opts = [];
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      opts.push(this.name);
    }
  });
  return opts;
}

function updateGames(opts){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "submit.php",
  dataType : 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: {filterOpts: opts},
  success: function(records){
    //show games depending on which values have been checked//
    }
 });
}
```

Also I've tried to write `submit.php` which would filter and return games depending on the checked properties. Now it returns an empty array. Here is the main problem, I'm not quite sure how should it work properly

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=games_db', 'root', '');
$opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';

$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT games.game_name FROM games INNER JOIN values ON attribute_id = attributes.attr_id WHERE value IN ($qMarks)');
$statement->execute($opts);
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close the `updateGames` function using `}`. You also forgot to close the ajax call in the same function using `)`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your `submit.php` code here.

Comment: Incidentally,   `value_id`  is redundant. You have a perfectly good unique key on `(entity_id,attribute_id)`

Comment: I don't understand what the desired result is.

Comment: @pgngp I've added my `submit.php` to the post

Comment: @Strawberry if I choose USA and 2002 - it shows only these games, which met these criteria, but if neither of checkboxes are checked - it shows all games

Comment: @sergaunt Do you get any errors or warnings when you run your php code? To print all warnings and errors in php, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` after the `<?php` tag.

Comment: @pgngp no errors, it just returns an empty array

Comment: @sergaunt The `select` statement is within single-quotes, so the variable `$qMarks` will probably not get substituted by its value. Can you retry by replacing the single-quotes with double-quotes?

Comment: @pgngp I've tried but result is still the same

Comment: @sergaunt Do you get the correct result when you run the `select` query directly in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I came up with a solution. So here is `games.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
  `attribute_id` int(255) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `attributes` (`attribute_id`, `attribute_name`) VALUES
(1, 'release'),
(2, 'developer'),
(3, 'country');

CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `game_id` int(255) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `game_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `games` (`game_id`, `game_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Grand Theft Auto Vice City'),
(2, 'Counter Strike 1.6'),
(3, 'Fallout 2'),
(4, 'Minecraft');

CREATE TABLE `games_values` (
  `game_id` int(255) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(255) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `games_values` (`game_id`, `attribute_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2002'),
(1, 2, 'Rockstar'),
(1, 3, 'USA'),
(2, 1, '2000'),
(2, 2, 'Valve'),
(2, 3, 'USA'),
(3, 1, '1998'),
(3, 2, 'Black Isle Studios'),
(3, 3, 'USA'),
(4, 1, '2011'),
(4, 2, 'Mojang'),
(4, 3, 'Sweden');

ALTER TABLE `games_values`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `games_values_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`attribute_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `games_values_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`game_id`);
```

and `submit.php`:

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=games', 'root', '');
$opts = $_GET['filterOpts'];
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT games.game_name FROM games INNER JOIN games_values ON games.game_id = games_values.game_id WHERE value IN ($qMarks)");
$statement->execute($opts);
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

The general idea of this issue of multiple checkbox filter was discussed in [this topic.](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/use-ajax-to-filter-mysql-results-with-multiple-checkbox-option/38018)

Would be great to hear from the experienced developers if this approach is productive enough. Thanks.